# Symfony 2 -- anonymous pages have empty "security.context" token?

Tags: php, symfony

When I do this in a controller:

```
$token = $this->get('security.context')->getToken();
```

The token is null if the controller is under an unprotected URL:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/public, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

In my case, the controller action is invoked on `/public`. The token exists if the code runs under `/` protected pages though.

The reason why I want this is because I want to include additional information in case the user is logged in, and I wanted to check for the existence of this "token".

Is there a better way to check if the user has logged in -- something that works in both protected and unprotected areas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if a user is authenticated by checking whether they are authenticated fully, that is, they are non-anonymous with the `isGranted` function.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException

public function editAction()
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted(
        'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'
       )) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
    // ...
}
```

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/remember_me.html#forcing-the-user-to-re-authenticate-before-accessing-certain-resources) for more info.